# How to create a reference to a smart_pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
std::ofstream x; 
std::ostream *foo = NULL; 
x.open(...); 
foo = &x; 
std::ostream *bar = diff? foo2() : foo; //foo2 is a function returning a new std::ostream(...) and has no side effects
std::ostream &bar1 = *foo; 
std::ostream &bar2 = *bar;
```

Here, bar is selectively a pointer that does not need deleting (`foo`) or a pointer created using new that needs to be deleted (`foo2()`).

I want to make bar a smart pointer (probably shared_ptr makes the most sense here) so I do not have to explicitly handle the delete in case the result of foo2 is assigned to it.

However that implies that I also make foo(and make foo2 return) a shared_ptr because unless I do that, I get a

```
free(): invalid pointer
free(): invalid pointer
```

error.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> foo2(..) {
   ...
   std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> ptr(new std::ofstream(...));
   return ptr;
}

...

std::ofstream x; 
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> foo(nullptr); 
x.open(...); 
foo.reset(&x); 
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> bar(diff? foo2() : foo); 
std::ostream &bar1 = *foo; 
std::ostream &bar2 = *bar;
```

Now, I get this error -

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
free(): invalid pointer
```

At first glance I think that making bar1 and bar2 shared_ptrs might fix the issue, but I am not sure how to do that considering that bar1 and bar2 are references to foo and bar. Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Please show a full [repro].

Comment: *"But, even after doing that I get the same error."* Please show us how you did **that**.

Comment: You want it to somehow know when it can delete when it has no way of knowing. Doesn't matter what types you choose.

Comment: @DeanSeo I updated the post with my attempt at making foo, bar and foo2() (return) a shared_ptr.

Comment: @walnut as is explained in the answer by eerorika, you cannot have a unique_ptr or a shared_ptr of a pointer that is conditionally owned (ie sometimes owned, sometimes not).  For a unique_ptr or a shared_ptr you must know whether you own it or not.  And then when you know that, you can choose how to manage it.  There is no in-between.

Comment: @SeanF You can use a custom deleter which conditionally deletes the pointer. But I agree that it is bad design, since it wouldn't completely have the usual semantics of the smart pointer. The "*completely fine*" portion of my comment referred to OP's first code block (which was the only one at that time), which I misread, as I am realizing now. Ok, it never was "*completely fine*", sorry!

Answer (score 1):

> bar is selectively a pointer that does not need deleting ... or a pointer ... that needs to be deleted
>
> I want to make bar a smart pointer

This is a bad design. It's better to use an unconditionally owning or unconditionally non-owning pointer rather than conditionally one or the other.

I suggest that you move everything that uses the ostream into separate function, and simply call that with one stream or the other:

```
void use_stream(std::ostream&);

if (diff) {
    auto ptr = foo2(); // some flavour of smart pointer
                       // use unique if you don't need shared
    use_stream(*ptr);
} else {
    std::ofstream foo(...);
    use_stream(foo);
}
```

However, it's preferable to return the stream by value from `foo2` unless you have some sort of dynamic polymorphism reasons to use indirection.